# How to scroll ListView to the last element programatically - Compact Framework

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework, autoscroll

I'm developping an application using the 3.5 Compact Framework on Windows Mobile 6.1. I have a `ListView` and I want to *autoscroll* this list when I add an item.

How can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
     listView.EnsureVisible(listView.Items.Count - 1);
```